# Vb.net: Check if an Excel Cell is Empty

Tags: excel, string, vb.net, null, vb.net-2010

I have the following code which given a `cellrow` and `cellcolumn` returns the value in a given Excel worksheet:

```
Public Function getCellValue(cellRow, cellColumn) As String
    Dim aString As String
    Dim xRng As Excel.Range
    Dim val As Object

    xRng = CType(xlSheet.Cells(cellRow, cellColumn), Excel.Range)
    val = xRng.Value()
    If val Is DBNull.Value Then 'thought this would work
        aString = "Null"
    Else
        aString = val.ToString
    End If
    Return aString
End Function
```

My issue is sometimes the cell is going to be empty. I thought the `DBNull.Value` check would work but it gives me an error. Any and all help is much appreciated!

ERROR: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Tutorial.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

EDIT: I know what a nullreferenceexception is, I am just looking for a way to check if an excel value IS null

Comment: `t gives me an error`  Is the error a secret?  Would you go to the doctor and say "it hurts" and expect a good diagnosis?

Comment: @Plutonix error added

Comment: @Plutonix the weirdest thing happened when I ctrl+f'd "Excel" in the question you said has an answer to this.. nothing popped up.

Comment: Excel has nothing to do with it; a null reference is a null reference.  If you cant be bothered to read it, find the section about **DBNull is not Nothing**.